# Categorical proof about mapping cone and connecting morphisms

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $\alpha:C\to D$ be a morphism of chain complexes in an abelian category, and denote by $\rm con$ the mapping cone of $\alpha$. There is an exact sequence of chain complexes: $$0\to D\to\mathrm{con}\to C[-1]\to 0.$$ I'm looking for a (categorical) proof that the connecting morphism $H_{n-1}(C)\to H_{n-1}(D)$ is $H_{n-1}(\alpha)$, for any $n$. I'm baffled by the fact that I arrived to an anticommutative square, which if it was commutative would lead to a proof. In other words, my proof doesn't work because of a minus sign: do you think it's a coincidence, and my attempt is vacuous,  or am I close to a proof?

I used latex diagrams where possible, but I needed an awkward diagram which I had to draw; I tried to be as clear as I could, I hope it's not a problem.  Thank you for your time, now I'll expose my "proof".

In the following, all differential morphisms of any chain complex will be denoted just $\partial$ (it shouldn't cause confusion). $Z$ and $B$ are used to denote kernels and images of differentials, as usual.

- By the Snake Lemma, the lower row of the diagram below is exact. $\require{AMScd}$ $$\begin{CD}  @.D_{n+1}@>>>  D_{n+1}\oplus C_n@>>>C_{n}@>>>0\\
  @. @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
  0@>>>D_{n}@>>>  D_{n}\oplus C_{n-1}@>>>C_{n-1}@>>>0\\
  @. @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
  @. \frac{D_n}{\partial (D_{n+1})}@>>> \frac{D_n\oplus C_{n-1}}{\partial (D_{n+1}\oplus C_n)}@>>>\frac{C_{n-1}}{\partial (C_{n})}@>>>0
  \end{CD}$$ Similarly, we recover another exact sequence. $$0\to Z_{n-1}(D)\to Z_{n-1}(\mathrm{con})\to Z_{n-2}(C)$$
- Then in the following diagram the rows are exact.
  $$\begin{CD}
  @. \frac{D_n}{\partial (D_{n+1})}@>>> \frac{D_n\oplus C_{n-1}}{\partial (D_{n+1}\oplus C_n)}@>>>\frac{C_{n-1}}{\partial (C_{n})}@>>>0\\
  @. @VVV @VVV @VVV @.\\
  0@>>> Z_{n-1}(D)@>>>  Z_{n-1}(\mathrm{con})@>>> Z_{n-2}(C)
  \end{CD}$$  The left vertical morphism is the unique one such that the composition below gives $\partial$ (the other vertical morphisms are obtained analogously). $$D_n\to\frac{D_n}{\partial (D_{n+1})}\to Z_{n-1}(D)\to D_{n-1}$$

Now we can refer to the drawing: the morphisms $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$, $g$ have just been defined.

- $h$ is the cokernel of $B_{n-1}(D)\to Z_{n-1}(D)$, as usual, but it is also the cokernel of $c$; $i$, $j$ are the pushout of $f$, $h$.
- $k$ is the cokernel of $B_{n-1}(C)\to Z_{n-1}(C)$, $l$ is the kernel of $C_{n-1}\to C_{n-2}$ and $m$ is the cokernel of $C_n\to C_{n-1}$. So $n$ is the unique morphism such that $nk=ml$, and it is also the kernel of $e$.
- $o$, $p$ are the pullback of $b$, $n$.
- $q$ is the canonical insertion in the biproduct, while $r$ is the cokernel of $D_{n+1}\oplus C_{n}\to D_n\oplus C_{n-1}$. So $m=brq$ (**wrong**).
- $s$ is the unique morphism such that $os=k$ and $ps=rql$ (**wrong**).
- $t$ is the connecting morphism, i.e. the unique morphism such that $jto=idp$.
- $u$ is the kernel of $D_{n-1}\to D_{n-2}$, $v$ is $\alpha_{n-1}$ and $w$ is the unique morphism such that $uw=vl$.
- $x$ is the canonical insertion in the biproduct, $y$ is the kernel of $D_{n-1}\oplus C_{n-2}\to D_{n-2}\oplus C_{n-3}$ and $z$ is the differential. So $xu=yf$ and $ydr=z$.

The proof was going on like this. The morphism $\alpha':=H_{n-1}(\alpha)$ is the unique one such that $\alpha'k=hw$, so the unique one such that $j\alpha' k=jhw$. To show that $t=\alpha'$ we can check that $jtk=jhw$ then. On one hand we have $jtk=jtos=idps$, and on the other $jhw=ifw$. So I tried to prove that $dps=fw$, or equivalently  $ydps=yfw$. On one hand we get $ydps=ydrql=zql$, on the other $yfw=xuw=xvl$. Hence I checked if $zql=xvl$, and I saw that actually $zql=-xvl$ (since in the differential $z$ the component $C_{n-1}\to D_{n-1}$ is $-\alpha_{n-1}$).

**Correction after comments.** In order to obtain a chain complex morphism $\mathrm{con}\to C[-1]$, such that every component $D_n\oplus C_{n-1}\to C_{n-1}$ is the canonical projection, the differentials of $C[-1]$ must be the *opposite* of the differentials of $C$. Therefore $m=-brq$, and $s$ satisfies $ps=-rql$. So $ydps=-ydrql=-zql$, which is indeed equal to $xvl$.

(Correction about the image: $e$ is drawn as an epi by mistake, its not epic) [image]

Comment: I am sorry, I did not yet read into details, however, as you get something anticommuting that seemingly should commute and used a shift, a classic trap is that people forget that shifting a complex actually introduces a sign into the differential. Could that help?

Comment: When you say "that the connecting morphism is $H_{n-1}(\alpha)$", I wonder what your initial definition of "the" connecting morphism is? I'm familiar with that term from the context of the Snake lemma, but specifically I'm not sure what you're trying to show $H_{n-1}(\alpha)$ equals

Comment: @FShrike consider the diagram made by $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$, $g$, which I said how to obtain; since $n$ is kernel of $e$ and $h$ is cokernel of $c$, the connecting morphism of the Snake Lemma is a morphism $t:H_{n-1}(C)\to H_{n-1}(D)$. Lemma 12.5.17 on the Stacks project says that such $t$ is the unique one such that $jto=idp$.

Comment: @Enkidu did you mean what I wrote in the first sentence of the paragraph "Correction after comments"?

Answer (score 1):

The minus sign appears because you (probably) defined the cone to have a shift in the "wrong" way. Define it instead so that the sequence has $C$ without a shift and $D$ with one, and the Koszul sign will disappear.

That is, I presume that the differential of your cone complex is $$\partial = \begin{pmatrix} d_D & -\alpha \\ 0 & -d_C \end{pmatrix}$$
on $D\oplus C[-1]$ where $-d_C$ comes from the shift $C[-1]$. If you follow the proof of the *Snake Lemma*, you pick an element $z\in C$ such that $dz=0$, then lift it to $(0,c)$ which has differential $(-\alpha(c),0)$, so
you indeed end up with $-H(\alpha)$. Note that this makes sense since what you get is a map $H(\alpha)[-1] : H(C[-1]) \longrightarrow H(D)[-1] \cong H(D[-1])$ and the $[-1]$ introduces the correct "Koszul sign".

Instead, consider the differential to be

$$\partial = \begin{pmatrix} -d_D & f \\ 0 & d_C \end{pmatrix}$$

on $D[1]\oplus C$. If you follow the proof of the *Snake Lemma*, you pick an element in $z\in C$ such that $dz= 0 $, this is covered by $(0,c)$ whose differential is $(f(c),0)$, and this gives you $H(\alpha)$, which is indeed the correct map $H(\alpha) : H(C) \longrightarrow H(D[1])[-1] = H(D)$,